# Why is my texture skewed despite the UV looking correct?

Tags: uv

I trying to make a room in Blender. I'm new to Blender, had some experience with Maya and C4D. I started by making a cube and flipping the normals to make the walls. I applied a texture to the floor which worked fine. But then applying the walls has me putting my head through a wall. I did a cube projection of the wall to unwrap it, however it looks like it's still projecting the texture from above, despite the UV editor showing exactly what I actually want.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out. I had attached a Mapping node to my texture to scale to texture, however it also inadvertently also fixed the rotation of the mapping to 0,0,0. Change it to 90,0,0.